# How to rename wordpress post title, if contains specifis char

Tags: mysql, regex, wordpress

I accidentally add `-` at the end of servral wordpress post titles. That mess up that posts making it unaccessable.

I want to delete that `-` char. So i have to delete `-` from the end.

`` select * from `wp_posts` where `post_name` like '%-' ``

is working properly. but i have no idea how to delete that `-` char. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you not log into the WordPress admin? In the admin, posts are only referenced by their post ID, they are not referenced by the post title.

Comment: Yes, i can login to Wordpress Panel. Problem is that over 5000 post contains `-` at the end. Post on my site was looking like that:
`site.com/post`

`site.com/post-blabla`
`site.com/post-bleble-bloblo-XXX`
`site.com/post-ble-blo-XXX`

And i used `REPLACE` to delete every `XXX` from `post_title`. Unfortunelly i did not deleted `-XXX` but `XXX` and now some of post contains `-` and the end. And when i try to go to that post it shows me error meaning that post doesnt exist.

Comment: That does not answer my question. Can you log into the WordPress admin or not? Why are you attempting to use MySQL to fix this problem instead of using the WordPress admin where you added the character in the first place?

Comment: As I said. Because there are too many post to repair.

Comment: You edited your response to include that after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `TRIM` function.

```
UPDATE wp_posts
  SET post_name = TRIM(TRAILING '-' FROM post_name);
```

Read more at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim